# Yarn cluster doesn't equally manage vcores, queue resource limit exceeded

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hadoop-yarn, jobs

I have 3 yarn node managers working in a yarn cluster, and an issue connected with vcores avalibity per yarn node.

For e.g., I have:

on first node : available 15 vcores, 
on second node : non vcores avalible,
on third node : available 37 vcores.

And now, job try to start and fails withe the error:

"Queue's AM resource limit exceeded"

Is this connected with the non vcores available on second node, or maybe I can somehow increase the resources limit in queue?

I also want to mention, that I have the following setting:

yarn.scheduler.capacity.maximum-am-resource-percent=1.0

Answer (score 4):

That means, that your drivers have exceeded max memory configured in Max Application Master Resources. You can either increase max memory for AM or decrease driver memory in your jobs.